# Relative paths to another relative path

Tags: node.js, express, internationalization, relative-path

I have a Node/Express server set up, and we are making the transition from subdirectories to sub domains for localisation, e.g.

```
es.example.com       // old way
www.example.com/es   // new way
```

Doing this for a variety of reasons, but mostly to facilitate the preservation of JWT login state across the internationalised content.

I have run into the problem of links generated dynamically - how to ensure they will preserve the subdirectory?

For example, if I am linking a user from index.html to `/user-profile/1000`, how can I maintain `/es/user-profile/1000`? Is there a way of having relative paths to other relative paths? If that even makes sense?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a middleware solution that redirects to the original paths. Here's a rudimentary example

```
var languages = ['en', 'es'], _ = require('lodash');
app.use("/:lang/*", function(req, res, next) {
    console.log(req.params, req.path);
    var found = _.find(languages, function(v) {
        return v === req.params.lang;
    });
    if (!!found) {
        res.redirect('/' + req.params[0]);
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

This will check for all valid languages and if it recognizes one, it will strip the language from the path and redirect to the original path minus language. Otherwise it will continue to the path provided.